# Transforming and reducing JSON files using Webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a series of static `JSON` files with translations of country names. Each file contains all the country names in a language. I have a config file with the languages that my system supports.

In my app, I only need the country names that correspond to the languages (i.e. I have the languages English, French and Spanish, so I want the countries UK, France and Spain).

I would like to use webpack to transform these JSON files and filter only the values I want but I couldn't find such a loader. Is there any loader that allows me to manipulate the loaded file?

Comment: So you want to concat all these JSON files into a single JSON file ??

Comment: No, I want to keep them separate, but reduce their size by removing all the unnecessary countries from them. The JSONs are provided by a third party and I rather not edit them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer was the [create-file-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-file-webpack). This plugin supports a transform property that is a JS function.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: 'countries/*',
    ignore: '../components/config/countries/readme.md',
    to: 'countries/[name].[ext]',
    transform: function (contents, path) {
      return "file contents here"
    }
  }
])
```